# datatable pagination is not working on dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datatable

I am using a .dataTable function for pagination&sorting . It works fine when page loads .I have a drop down list in the website and the table content changes based on the selection. Once the user changes the drop down ,the content displays correctly but pagination &sorting functionality disappears . here is my javascript
for pagination

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dtTable').dataTable({
   "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false, "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5] }
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[2, 4, 8, -1], [2, 4, 8, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 4
        });
    });
```

And my drop down change event function :

```
    $("#SelectName").change(function () {
        var DropDownSelectedValue = parseInt($("#Name :selected").val());

        if ($("#Name").prop('selectedIndex')==0) {
            DropDownSelectedValue = 0;
        }
        var city = $("#txtSearchCityOrZip").val();
         if (DropDownSelectedValue != null) {

             var data = {Code:DropDownSelectedValue,Name:DropDownSelectedText}
             $("#_IndexPartialView").load('@(Url.Action("GetNameData", "Home"))', { Name: DropDownSelectedValue,CityOrZip:city });


        }
    });
```

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="grid-100">
        <div id="cn" class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-4" }, displayOptions: DisplayOptions.None)
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, Model.Countries, "--Select Name--", new { onchange = "SelectName()", id = "Name", @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchCityOrZip)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchCityOrZip, new { id = "txtSearchCityOrZip" })
            <input type="button" value="Search" id="search" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="_IndexPartialView">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndexPartialView", Model); }
    </div>

}
```

Comment: I think the issue is the position of your dropdown element id. Share the code for html.

Comment: Thanks .. I have updated my post ..  Please check now

Comment: What error you get on console before(if any) and after dropdown pressed?

Comment: I am not getting any error .. I am populating data on the html table  based on the dropdown selection & search button .. after the drop down selection /or  button event ,my pagination and sorting functionality disappears ... ie It is available only on page onload  and after server submit it disappears

Comment: One thing for sure there's nothing wrong with program but it's likely that there is an issue with design like say for example you have a style attribute like overflow hidden.